# Play2 testing controller methods using Action composition

Tags: unit-testing, scala, playframework-2.0

I want to test a controller action using Action composition.
Here's an example of the composed action and its test code.

The Secured trait:

```
trait Secured {
   def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get(Security.username)
   def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Auth.login)

   def withAuth(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
      Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
        Action(request => f(user)(request))
   }
}
```

The controller:

```
MyController extends Contrller with Secured {
   def simple = Action { Ok("ok") }
   def simpleWithauth = withAuth { implicit username => implicit request=> Ok("ok") }
}
```

The test code:

```
// This work fine
val result1 = controller.simple()(FakeRequest())

// This wont compile
val result2 = controller.simpleWithAuth()(FakeRequest())
```

The latter would require a **Request[Action[AnyContent], AnyContent]**
 but FakeRequest returns a **Request[AnyContent]**

Any pointers on how to create a fake request of the appropriate type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I had to do to test secured action

```
def wrappedActionResult[A](wrapped: Action[(Action[A], A)], request: Request[A]): Result = wrapped.parser(request).run.await.get match {
  case Left(errorResult) => errorResult
  case Right((innerAction, _)) => innerAction(request)
}
```

and the test

```
    running(app) {
      val result = wrappedActionResult(FakeController().securedAction, invalidRequest)
      status(result) must_== UNAUTHORIZED
      contentAsString(result) must_== "must be authenticated"
    }
```

That doesn't work with Play 2.1 though, types have been changed...

**UPDATE:**
in Play 2.1 it's even easier

I've added some sugar

```
implicit class ActionExecutor(action: EssentialAction) {
  def process[A](request: Request[A]): Result = concurrent.Await.result(action(request).run, Duration(1, "sec"))
}
```

and the test now looks like this

```
  running(app) {
    val result = FakeController().securedAction process invalidRequest
    status(result) must_== UNAUTHORIZED
    contentAsString(result) must_== "must be authenticated"
  }
```

**UPDATE**: here is a related blog post i wrote sometime ago
http://www.daodecode.com/blog/2013/03/08/testing-security-dot-authenticated-in-play-2-dot-0-and-2-dot-1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the routeAndCall approach?

```
val Some(result) = routeAndCall(FakeRequest(POST, "/someRoute"))
```

You can add whatever parameters you need in your request with the asFormUrlEncodedBody method and/or adding things to the session with the withSession method.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but don't see why it wouldn't work. Although I wanted to specifically unit test that one method without e.g. involving routing, but I guess the more pragmatic approach would be using routeAndCall for now.

Comment: The problem is, i think, that Request and FakeRequest work in a different way and you cannot get around that in the way you would want. I cannot swear that it is so tho so dont quote me ;) This git project also helped me some with other auth testing issues i had with play and scala: https://github.com/maffoo/play-test-security